# Pay the difference; Can I pay later

Tags: word-choice

> I'll make up for the difference.
>
> I'll pay the difference.
>
> I'll pay the rest.
>
> I'll pay the remaining $12(money).

Here in the sentences above, a person is offering to make up for the difference for a customer who is $12 short.

And these sentences:

> Can I pay the remaining $5 later?
>
> Can I pay the difference later?
>
> Can I pay the rest later?
>
> Can I make up for the difference later?
>
> Can I pay next time? (Does "the" have to be included here?)
>
> Can I pay the remaining $5 next time?/ Can I make up for/ pay the difference next time?

A regular customer $5 short. The shopkeeper knows him well, thus, the customer asks if he can pay later.

Out of all these sentences which one is the least likely to be used?

Comment: The think the question "Can I pay the rest later?" would be most uncommon of them. At least I have heard it rarely as compared to the others.

Answer (score 1):

Those are all fine in my standard North American dialect, except "make up for", which means to remedy some wrong or failing. One can say "make up" the difference, but that's what the remaining $5 does, not the customer.

Of the others, "pay the rest" and "pay the difference" are the most likely to come out of my mouth. "Remaining" sounds a bit technical (like the solution to a math problem) and I would likely say "the other $5" instead.

Note that "Can I pay next time?" suggests that you intend to pay it all next time, and nothing now.

You don't need to use "the" before "next time", no. That's more common when relating past events: "The next time he visited the shop, he paid the other $5."

--

By the by, this reminds me of a cultural nuance I once saw tested. I was buying a couple slices of pizza and the guy on cash was, by his accent, probably a first-generation immigrant. The total was $5.10 and since I happened to have a $5 bill and a dime, I could pay exact change. But he refused to take my dime: "No, no, we don't worry about five and ten cents, no? Isn't that right?" He had almost gotten it... Yes, he's right, except in cases where the customer has it in hand and is giving it to you! You forgive the dime only after the customer makes a show of hunting for change for about 500 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll make for the difference

is something I have never heard. At least in my region of the US, it is not idiomatic.

> I'll make up the difference

or

> I'll make up for the difference

are idiomatic.

Other than that, all would be idiomatic.

Comment: I've edited it.... It's 'make up for"

Comment: In light of your edit, my answer now becomes that all these formulations are idiomatic and have the same meanings. I doubt anyone has studied which would be used with more frequency in which regions and contexts and during which periods. My best guess is that, in the US of today, the more concise "make up" will be more frequent than "make up for" and that the less mathematical term "rest" will be more frequent than "difference." But that is opinion based only on personal experience.

Comment: In this context "make up for the difference" is not idiomatic where I am.